# How to delete a branch in hg?

Tags: version-control, mercurial

I am recently learning git, and found people can delete short branches, but in Hg, after merging the branch to default, how could I delete it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot. You can close the branch to hide it from the list of active branches, but you cannot completely delete it.

This happens because in mercurial and in git the "branch" term means different things.

In mercurial - it is a set of changesets.

And in git - it is a pointer to a particular changeset.

Comment: how could I close a merged branch in tortoiseHg?

Comment: @shengy: `hg commit --close-branch`

Comment: @shengy: From the commit window there is a label, above the commit window, which says which branch you are on.  Clicking this brings up a dialog box which gives three options.  The third option is to close the current branch.  This is also where you create a new branch.

Comment: @SteveKaye I did exactly this, but then it said my head is closed now, and when I returned to my default branch, it is no longer the tip. Have I done it wrong?

Comment: I did exactly this, but then it said my `head` is closed now, and when I returned to my `default` branch, it is no longer the `tip`. Have I done it wrong? How do I move the `tip` back my `default`? I used the `update` method, so I was expecting to get back to default correctly...

Comment: @Hannes `tip` just points the latest commit.  As soon as you make another commit that one will be the new `tip`. See the description of the tip command for an explanation https://www.mercurial-scm.org/repo/hg/help/tip