# In Mercurial how can I delete a local branch?

Tags: mercurial

How can I delete a local branch in Mercurial using terminal or TortoiseHg?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11681218/how-to-delete-a-branch-in-hg

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Discard a local branch in Mercurial before it is pushed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6989262/discard-a-local-branch-in-mercurial-before-it-is-pushed)

Answer (score 1):

In Mercurial, the existence of a branch is implied by the existence of commits that are in/on that branch.  Hence to delete a branch, you must strip out all the commits that are in/on that branch.  The simplest way to do that is using `hg strip`.  See [Is there any way to delete local commits in Mercurial?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2338986/1256452)

(Note that there are some tricky conditions when commits within the branch are parents of merges.  It's probably unwise to try to remove a branch that has ever been merged to anything.)